# Using PostSharp and Paket together ignores under some circumstances the weaving compiler run

Tags: postsharp, paket

I have used [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) and [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) for a while together in a project w/o any issues.

After a while, the weaving compiler was not more triggered and **PostSharp** therefore useless.
With some investigation, I could identify the root cause but I have no idea how to solve it.

Summary: by introducing the **NuGet** package for **PostSharp** some things behind the scenes happen. With converting to **Paket** these things still work (in minimum on the machine where it was converted), as long no `git cleanup -dxf` is done. Additionally a `git clone` will also omit **PostSharp** after the conversion to **Paket**.

Under [Github: PostSharpAndPaket](https://github.com/mapfel/PostSharpAndPaket) a detailed analysis is available.

Comment: For some reason Paket does not add import of `PostSharp.targets` to the project file. I see the following warning when running `paket install -v`: `Could not detect any platforms from 'unzipper' in 'C:\Dev\Support\25520\PostSharpAndPaket\packages\PostSharp\build\unzipper\unzipper.runtimeconfig.json', please tell the package authors`. This tool was added in PostSharp 6.3, which might be the reason why you've started experiencing the problem only recently.

Comment: @Daniel: with your hint, I have played with some older **PostSharp** versions. You are right, the issue was introduced with version 6. The latest version 5.0.55 doesn't have this issue but throws another warning because of incompatible C# language versions (only support till 7,1; but later one used). But the AOP works. I have enhanced the project readme with this finding. But this could only be treated as a temporary workaround. It needs a solution for the newest version.
You are an employee of PostSharp Technologies, so could you step in to move that issue into your internal bug tracker?

Comment: I'm afraid we will not be able to change this, because we need the tool to be available for our MSBuild tasks. You can use PostSharp 6.2 which does not need the cross platform extraction tool.

Comment: Moreover the output that Paket gives does not tell us enough about what actually is the cause.

Comment: The complete 6er line is not working. You are right, that the cross-platform extraction tool is not throwing the warning above, but it throws now `Could not detect any platforms from 'unzipper' in 'C:\_projects\github\mapfel\PostSharpAndPaket\packages\PostSharp\build\unzipper\SharpCompress.dll', please tell the package authors`.